# How to recognize stored procedure name by using regex?

Tags: sql-server, regex, stored-procedures

Is there any way to recognize the SP name as well as all parameter name and type?
The regex pattern I used can only recognize the SP name and the last parameter name.  I'll be appreciated if anyone can provide an regex that is able to recognize the SP name along with all the parameter names.

*Pattern:*

```
.*create procedure\s+.*\.\[(?<spname>\w+)\].*\((.*(?<aname>\@\w+)\s+(?<atype>\w+).*)\).*procedure
```

*Below is the target string:*

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('SPNameToBeRecognized') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1)
            DROP PROCEDURE SPNameToBeRecognized
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNameToBeRecognized] 
    (
            @FirstArg DATETIME = NULL,
            @SecondArg DATETIME = NULL,
            @ThirdArg SMALLINT = 814,
            @FouthArg SMALLMONEY = 10.00
    ) 
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Procedure   :
```

Comment: Are you using the regex in .NET? You may use something like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=create+procedure%5cs%2b.*%5c.%5c%5b%28%3f%3cspname%3e%5cw%2b%29%5c%5d%5cs*%5c%28%28%3f%3a%5cs*%28%3f%3caname%3e%40%5cw%2b%29%5cs%2b%28%3f%3catype%3e%5cw%2b%29%5cW.*%29*%5cs*%5c%29&i=CREATE+PROCEDURE+%5bdbo%5d.%5bSPNameToBeRecognized%5d+%0d%0a%28%0d%0a++++++++%40FirstArg+DATETIME+%3d+NULL%2c%0d%0a++++++++%40SecondArg+DATETIME+%3d+NULL%2c%0d%0a++++++++%40ThirdArg+SMALLINT+%3d+814%2c%0d%0a++++++++%40FouthArg+SMALLMONEY+%3d+10.00%0d%0a%29&o=i) there and access each named group capture collection.

Comment: If this *is* .NET (or you have the option to use it), consider leveraging the [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser) classes and/or SSDT database projects for such tasks. That's vastly more reliable than trying to capture the arcane T-SQL syntax with regexes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this still captures only one of the parameter.  Is there a way to capture all the parameters along with the SP name?
For example, I want the regex to tell me that it matches the <spname> as well as 4 <anames> and 4 <atypes>

Comment: @mind1n No, it *captures* all of them, but writes into a group only the last occurrence.